# Selenium support (native and its bindings)

Tags: selenium, documentation, defect-tracking

As far as I am aware, Selenium is an active project that is being developed and heavily used. However, when I look at the [defects list](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list) on their official site, it looks like there are thousands of Open/New defects/enhancements that just sit there for years and being taken care of. Any idea why that so?

The other question I had is regarding Selenium bindings. For example Python. If I'm using Selenium in Python flavor and find a defect, where do I submit it? I would assume there will be a separate repository for such defects. Any idea how that works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Selenium is an active project (see commit history on [GitHub](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commits/master)).

Then why are there so many unresolved open issues?

- It's open source. We can't expect the team members to fix bugs on a daily basis, because they are just enthusiasts and all have real-life jobs. The developer in charge of a particular area may not have time to deal with it right away, even if an issue is confirmed by others. However,

  - If it is an urgent case, someone will stand up or at least get someone to fix it.
  - You are more than welcome to submit your own fixes/patches.
- Many cases are poorly raised. Those were opened by irresponsible users. Some people tend to open issues without providing enough information to reproduce and never come back to check the progress. Some of those issues will remain open for a long time and be marked with `NeedsClarification` tag.
- It doesn't work like a FIFO queue. It doesn't mean old cases have to be fixed first. Ones with higher priority will be dealt with first.
- Just like any other projects (regardless of open source or commercial), it is common that there are heaps of unresolved cases sitting around. Don't be surprised at all.

If you have found a Selenium bug in Python binding, please submit it [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list), just like all other issues. Team members will have a look at it and notify relevant people. But please bear in mind that you might need to specify the **exact** environment and all steps needed for anyone to **reproduce**.

For example, [Issue 7739](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7739) was raised on Aug 12 2014. Six days later, project member barancev had a look and tagged it with `Lang-Python`, then notified David Burns and luke.semerau.